# When the HR.EMPID is not found

Tags: sql, oracle

My code seems to disregard the entries that I cannot find the HR.NAME.  How do I get "Not Found" in the field "SENT BY"?  Plus, if it doesn't find the HR.NAME, include that data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MA.MOPID "MOP #"
   ,MA.MOPNOTIFICATIONSENT "Sent Status"
   ,MA.MOPNOTIFICATIONSENTBY "Employee ID"
   ,MA.MOPNOTIFICATIONSENDAT  "Date Sent"
   ,HR.NAME "SENT BY"

FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY MA ,HR@SECADMIN HR
WHERE TO_CHAR(MOPNOTIFICATIONSENDAT, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND HR.EMPID = SUBSTR(MA.MOPNOTIFICATIONSENTBY, 2, (LENGTH(MA.MOPNOTIFICATIONSENTBY) - 1))
```

Comment: I noticed that the first field you access using your DBLink is `HR.Name` so my guess is that either the field doesnt exist with that name. Or you dont have access. Can you access the fields in `HR@SECADMIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `COALESCE` function with `left join`

```
SELECT DISTINCT MA.MOPID "MOP #"
   ,MA.MOPNOTIFICATIONSENT "Sent Status"
   ,MA.MOPNOTIFICATIONSENTBY "Employee ID"
   ,MA.MOPNOTIFICATIONSENDAT  "Date Sent"
   ,COALESCE(HR.NAME,'Not found') as "SENT BY"

FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY MA 
left join HR@SECADMIN HR on HR.EMPID = SUBSTR(MA.MOPNOTIFICATIONSENTBY, 2, (LENGTH(MA.MOPNOTIFICATIONSENTBY) - 1))
WHERE TO_CHAR(MOPNOTIFICATIONSENDAT, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```